# Deploying to ec2 (preferably via git)

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've always used heroku free version, that's why deploying has always been easy (via `git push` to my `heroku`'s repo and that was it). Now I'm trying amazon ec2. Can I do the same for ec2? If not, what could I do, preferably via git.

Yes, I know I can do that via `scp`. Well, that's one of the options, but it's not so sensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a Heroku-style deployment, I would recommend installing [dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku). The project is very clever and reading the code will give some insight into how Heroku make deployments painless (buildpacks). It won't do any form of auto-scaling, it's designed to work on a single hosts.

A quick google found the following tutorial on setting it up on Amazon:

http://mircozeiss.com/dokku-in-depth-tutorial-your-private-saas-on-amazon-ec2/